# How to convert image url to base64 in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello i have a code that gets the image url from database and i want to convert it to base64 before i show it as a response, but i have problem first the base64 string is very short and when i follow the steps online i get erros.

This is what i have tried until now, i have a resource with this code:

`'images' => $this->convertToBase64($this->getImages($this->coordination_id)->pluck('image')) ?? '',`

Then in the model i have this code:

```
public function convertToBase64($imagePath)
    {
        $images = public_path($imagePath);

        $image = "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($images));

        dd($image);
    }
```

But i get this error:

**"file_get_contents(/home/User/Desktop/test_project/public/["/files/AgpjxTNKE0IoFRb-2023-07-11-10:08:03.jpeg","/files/AgpjxTNKE0IoFRb-2023-07-11-10:08:03.jpeg"]): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory",
"exception": "ErrorException",**

While the file path is this: **/files/AgpjxTNKE0IoFRb-2023-07-11-10:08:03.jpeg**, what am i doing wrong? the base64 response that i mentioned above that is very short is this: **L2ZpbGVzL0FncGp4VE5LRTBJb0ZSYi0yMDIzLTA3LTExLTEwOjA4OjAzLmpwZWc=**

Comment: It is an array i am using a foreach in the model function the outout of the dd is ```/files/AgpjxTNKE0IoFRb-2023-07-11-10:08:03.jpeg```

Comment: but the problem is when i use file_get_content for the path makes error